# elasticsearch: custom score function, multi match query and per_field boosting

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch.
I want to search for previously tagged documents. Each tag in a document has a weight that indicates the importance of the tag for that praticular document.

The user gives some search terms (words or phrases), and the engine should return documents tagged with these (or similar) terms. I created a mapping with a nested type and multiple fields. Bellow I copy part of my mapping definition.

```
 "properties": {
       "weighted_tags": {
           "type": "nested",
           "properties": {
               "tags": {
                  "type": "text",
                   "analyzer": "synonym",
                   "fields": {
                       "eng": {
                          "type": "text",
                          "analyzer": "english",
                          "search_analyzer": "english"
                       },
                       "raw": {
                           "type": "keyword"
                       }
                   }
               },
               "tag_weight": {
                   "type": "float"
               }
           }
       } }
```

I need to score my search results according to how good the document tags match the search term and the weight of that tag for each document. Therefore, I want to define my own scoring function disregarding the default function based on tf-idf.

The solution I found so far is to use function_score and multi_match queries, boosting fields according to their relevance for the search, as illustrated bellow:

```
"nested": {
    "path": "weighted_tags",
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": ["weighted_tags.tags^1", "weighted_tags.tags.eng^5", "weighted_tags.tags.raw^10"]
                    "query": "happy new year",
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            },
            "script_score": {"doc[\"weighted_tags.tag\"].value"}
            "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are: How can I use the boosting weights (1, 5 and 10 in the example) on my script_score? Are the boosting wights useful when combined with "boost_mode": "replace"? Is there any better solution for the problem I just described?

Thank you in advance,
Renata Rego

Comment: May you please also provide a couple of examples of the documents and maybe their desired scores? I suppose field `weighted_tags.tags` is a free text, right? Can there be several items (practically a list) of `weighted_tags`? `weighted_tags.tags`? `weighted_tags.tag_weight`? Another thing: how exactly do you want to combine the scores of the query matching and the weight? Do you want to completely remove the default one or just multiply it by `tag_weight`?  Thank you.

Comment: May you please also provide a couple of examples of the documents and maybe their desired scores? I suppose field `weighted_tags.tags` is a free text, right? Can there be several items (practically a list) of `weighted_tags`? `weighted_tags.tags`? `weighted_tags.tag_weight`? Another thing: how exactly do you want to combine the scores of the query matching and the weight? Do you want to completely remove the default one or just multiply it by `tag_weight`?  Thank you.